# Questions about length key of RSA 2048 bit

Tags: rsa, keys

I use putty gen to generate RSA key, I choose length of key is 2048 bit, it generate public key:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEA10prz5/FvHX7cx5aowiF+eO8uQuKTYSU0rA0x5yNPD5yTI0HGmEBTnhia4iOhOzwg0BevOZR1SClBpCRTZViym2Z+ohAGt65mWq+2LLhRf3MNpcM6Ttm8IXFxRiVR9iALk9cPsXu6zz4x7RT9vZG7rE1+KbeeSn1gacpCeudsEYCDOrgenH78hNXCLcc6TdKOWnBlASf8coj/T1czUW78S9tcqu7bFrR7N6xfj9M0d8e8oyBOqYrhv3uFmLxvVQ2yxZrJ0ILhAf8KhrflX6SytO5s/K5zTWRkjhwg83V8Qs30LWd79xJgpaUESaWFeS17x6iit8uEjMtPqBGnqLryw== rsa-key-20160620
```

I don't know why this key is 2048 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary base 64 encoded blob contains a modulus which is 257 bytes in size:

```
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
```

The first byte is set to `00` to indicate that it is a positive number. 256 bytes equals 2048 bits, which is the size of the modulus. The modulus in turn defines the key size of RSA.

Comment: Would you like to give me some scripts for demonstration?

Comment: Sorry, previous comments were about PGP instead of SSH (they use a binary format that has some identical features). I did not use a script for this, I just looked at the binary values.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I deleted the previous comments about PGP. I was indicating that I was wrong footed and that those should be ignored to the author. Nothing more. Yes of course big endian two complement 8 bit bytes etc etc.